# Is it possible to dump firmware of a device via USB port?

Tags: firmware, arm, usb, dump

I have a device which can be connected via USB port. The vendor of this device provides a tool for upgrading firmware of this device via USB port.
`lsusb` command says that this device has following VendorID and ProductID 0483:5748 STMicroelectronics Program Upgrade V1.0. So I assume that this device is STM based. My question is - if there is a tool for uploading firmware to device via USB, is there a way of downloading current firmware of this device via USB back to my PC? And if there is such way, how do I do that? I stumbled across some links on the Internet like this one https://medium.com/techmaker/reverse-engineering-stm32-firmware-578d53e79b3 it recommends to use `openocd` tool. But in my case `openocd` just gives me an error

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0-rc2
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
WARNING: interface/stlink-v2.cfg is deprecated, please switch to interface/stlink.cfg
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Error: open failed
```